# Youtube VIdeo direct download links "Access to SERVERNAME was denied" error?

Tags: networking, download, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create a simple Youtube video downloader program to sharpen my skills in both C++ and the Qt library .

**To be clear the problem isn't with the code it's on the networking side of the program** .

So what I've got so far is :

- **first** get the video info from  http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=ID  , where ID is the id of the video
- **Secondly** fetch the response for the videos direct download links with their different itags

## The Problem

When I try to access the direct download links I get an error "Access to SERVERNAME was denied " like this [LINK](https://r18---sn-i5h7ln7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=18&requiressl=yes&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=982500&pl=23&fexp=930827,9407%20141,9407535,9407713,9408142,9408420,9408710,940917%200,9410773,9412958,9413503,9415304,9416126,9416329,%209416456,952640&key=yt5&upn=glRoyFGA0ec&ratebypass=%20yes&mm=31&lmt=1411065252274357&expire=1435166991&m%20n=sn-i5h7ln7s&mt=1435145272&mv=m&ms=au&ip=217.71.46.107%20&source=youtube&sver=3&mime=video/mp4&signature=B31CDB6BF6F394517625654F83D226EE41CB%20AE0D.1F181620CB4BDE450187E89F5F18E5546FA7EC9B&dur=%201153.102&id=o-AOYJ9JCS9QUyLk_9mGm6PSqiCis8R3J21PutrGKSWNK4&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,u%20pn,expire&title=Seenekas%20Allarile%20Nature%20and%20Life,%2%200Open%20Source%20Human%20clips)

I've been Googling for hours now with no hope , I've read the "Youtube Data Api V3" wich has no way to download the videos because it's against their terms of service , and the old method of downloading the video " www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=ID&t=TOKEN&fmt=FORMAT_ID " no longer works, so can someone please tell me how to solve this error , PLEASE

Comment: *"To be clear the problem isn't with the code it's on the networking side of the program."* - Then why the c++ and qt tags?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I removed them, thank's for the note